# Can I autofill the formulae in new columns of a Table using relative references

Tags: excel, reference, excel-2019

I have a table, it has a few columns

[image: Table]

It has formulae like this:

[image: Table formulae]

And I would like to fill more pairs of columns like this:

[image: Filled Table]

*Column "A 2" has the same formula as "A 1", but with the reference offset by 2 columns. Or generally "A i" & "B i" refer to "B (i-1)".*

I've tried selecting columns A1 & B1 and dragging right, also using copy & paste. The problem is, when you drag a pair of columns in a table, the references offset by 1 cell. If I drag a pair of columns that use normal cell references rather than table indexing, the cells offset by 2 as I want.

I'd just like to add pairs of columns to the table, where the formulae point to the previous pair (so all their references need to offset by 2 table columns). What's the best way to achieve this?

My real table has many rows and many columns, and I'd prefer not to use `Offset` or switch to non-table style cell references (`[@[blah]]`) if possible (for performance and readability respectively)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use an IF to choose which formula to use:

```
=IF(ISODD(COLUMN(A1)),[@[B 0]]+1,[@[B 0]]^2)
```

Where the `A1` is only there as a counter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a great unproach; but unfortunately because Excel evaluates both arguments for `IF`, I don't think it will be very performant (my actual data has 5 columns to copy, not just a pair, so every cell would evaluate 5 formulae).

Comment: The formula IF does not evaluate both arguments, it only evaluates the condition and the argument that the condition requires.  `IIF` in vba does both arguments but not the worksheet function `IF`. and with 5 I would use CHOOSE(), which also does not evaluate all, only the one chosen.